# When devcontainer setup is finished, I want it to be in a state waiting for input

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer, devcontainer

### My Problem

When devcontainer setup is finished, the terminal is usually in this state, with logs flowing.

[image: Bad]

Instead, can you make it so that it is waiting for input from the user when the setup is finished, as in the following image?

[image: good]

For example, GitPod automatically enters a state waiting for input at the end of setup.